# flex-direction seems to break horizontal margin auto in Safari 10

Tags: css, flexbox

I was trying to use flex-direction column along with margin: auto for a child element in Safari 10, but the horizontal margins don't seem to apply while they do in literally every other browser (Edge, Firefox, Chrome). Here's a quick repro:

http://jsfiddle.net/paostj73/

```
.center-pls {
  display: flex;
  height: inherit;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.to-center {
  margin: auto;
}
```

It looks like this in Safari:
[image]

And like this in Chrome:
[image]

I know that setting align-items is a workaround, but unfortunately, it also happens to break other parts of my layout. Is there another way to fix this, and is this already a known issue?

Comment: I think Safari has a bug where auto margin and `align-items`, which defaults to `stretch`, is the cause. What if you add `align-items: flex-start;` to the `.center-pls` rule?

Comment: Also, the above make it work on IE

Comment: Do note, in this case, instead of setting `align-items: center` to the parent, you can add `align-self: center;` to `to-center`, which will only affect the item itself, keeping your overall layout untouched

Comment: I don't have access to Safari, so let me know if above worked and I can post it as an answer

Comment: I tried flex-start and then had to manually specify some width: 100%s, but it seemed to work.

Comment: Posted an answer, does that work in Safari?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue IE has, and if I'm not mistaken Safari too, caused by the `align-items` default value `stretch`, which stretch the element to full width and fail to apply the auto margin.

To keep the default, `align-items: stretch` for all items but the `to-center` element, add `align-self: center` to its rule

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.center-pls {
  display: flex;
  height: inherit;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.to-center {
  margin: auto;
  align-self: center;           /*  added, fix for IE and Safari  */
}
```

```html
<div class="center-pls">
  <div class="top-nav">
  aaa aaa aa
  </div>
  <div class="to-center">
  aaaa
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Based on how the other elements are suppose to render, setting `align-items: flex-start` to the `center-pls`, will also work, though then the other elements might need `width: 100%` set, so they *stretch* and fill their parent's width.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.center-pls {
  display: flex;
  height: inherit;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;      /*  added, fix for IE and Safari  */
}

.to-center {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="center-pls">
  <div class="top-nav">
  aaa aaa aa
  </div>
  <div class="to-center">
  aaaa
  </div>
</div>
```